# Wiring for DSL/ISDN and Ethernet over a single Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, dsl

I tried to wire a ISDN/DSL and a Ethernet back over one Cat cable. (everything connects over RJ45 plugs) The reason is that there is only one Ethernet wire from where the router and phone are to the closet with all the ethernet connections are and the DSL comes in.

I used an adapter like you can see in the image below.

Now the ISDN connection (using pin 4,5) is working fine, but the ethernet doesn't work. As far as I know ethernet should work in 100 mbit/s mode when it only has the 4 pins (1,2,3,6), but it does not.

Any ideas how I could get this to work?

[image: adapter]

Answer (score 0):

*Some* Gigabit Ethernet NICs fall back to 100 Mbit/s when there are only two pairs connected (mostly Broadcom-based). Many don't.

Primarily, *Auto Negotiation* is used to select speed and duplex. When both sides support Gigabit, they'll try to link with it. With only two pairs in a cable, that is bound to fail. If none of the link partners falls back to 100M ("Ethernet at wire speed"), Auto Negotiating and failing to link repeat indefinitely.

If one of the sides supports "Auto 100" it stops advertising Gigabit and the link should succeed with 100M.

Probably all NICs support *manual speed and duplex*, disabling Auto Negotiation (AN) entirely. Without AN, duplex negotiation fails and falls back to half duplex. So, you need to configure manual speed and duplex *on both sides* identically to avoid a duplex mismatch. Failing that, you could use manual 100M/*half* duplex on one side and the other will follow up.

Comment: But would the whole Ethernet connection fail as a result? Look at the wiring description in the image.

Comment: Yes, unless one of the sides stops advertising 1000BASE-T and falls back to 100BASE-TX.

Comment: Thanks! I now got it to work. Sadly it only works with 10 mbit/s. as far as i know 10 and 100 use the exact same cable and shoud funktion over 5e cable without a problem. the adapter also says it supports 100. Any idea wey this choud be?

Comment: 10 or 100 Mbit/s doesn't make a difference - the cable isn't tested, it's all about advertising speed/duplex. If the cable is sub-standard you'll get a load of errors. Maybe it's a driver bug. Have you tried setting "10"? Maybe it's mixed up. Updating the driver might help as well.